# How can I use median of leaf instead of mean in LightGBM Regression

Tags: regression, decision-tree, lightgbm

I have a dataset with 6 numeric inputs and a numeric target col to predict. I'm using LightGBM and getting considerable good results. As far as I know, predicted values are the learning rate weighted averages of the tree leaves. And each leaf's value is the mean of observations it contains. But I suspect that the observations in each leaf may not be normally distributed. So I want to use median value, or maybe trim_mean, of each leaf instead of mean. Is there an option for this?